# Edit datetime format in python (using datetime.strptime)

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, datetime

I am trying to update my datetime format to be in the m/d/y h:m:s string format and am getting it in the wrong response format.I need to be able to load the dates from python --> csv --> sqlite3 which has TEXT data type. See code below:

Request:

```
original_date = '1/6/2019 1243'
new_date = datetime.strptime(original_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
```

Result:

`2019-06-01 12:43:00`

Wanted Result: (m/d/y h:m:s)

`'01/06/2019 12:43:00'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `strftime()` function which takes **datettime** object as input and returns formatted **string**:

```
original_date = '1/6/2019 1243'
new_date = datetime.strptime(original_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
new_date_string = datetime.strftime(new_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `datetime.strptime()` will give you an object of datetime, which will store all the required information (e.g. day, month, year, etc.). Yet, it does not contain any formatting and printing it will use the standard format.

If you need a date string in a specific format, you have to use `datetime.strftime()`:

```
original_date = '1/6/2019 1243'
date_obj = datetime.strptime(original_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H%M')
new_date_str = datetime.strftime(date_obj, ''%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

You have to distinguish two cases:

1. Generate `datetime` object from string: Use `strptime()`
2. Generate (formatted) string from `datetime` object: Use `strftime()`